# Free open-source on-premise file sharing server

Tags: open-source, web-apps, file-management, file-synchronization

I'm looking for a free & open source file sharing solution that could be installed an on-premise server of my company.

Ideally, the solution would meet these requirements:

- Handle easily 1Gb files up & down.
- Can provide shared "virtual" drive on the network, to be used by scanners for instance.
- Not necessairly having to edit the files on the server.
- Has a decent active community.
- Written in java, python, but not php.
- Ability to create share link.
- Can be connected to LDAP service.

Comment: For web or desktop ? With login or 'public' ? Encrypted ? Is it supposed to send links after upload ? Shall files expire ? For which OS ? Which language ? Php ? What makes a file big ? 500mb ? 1 Petabyte ?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Having done that, you can request your question to be re-opened of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/). It is open source and can install on premise.

According to your requirements:

- [Uploading big files](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual//configuration_files/big_file_upload_configuration.html)
- It can expose the drive via [WebDAV](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html)
- There ares some [collaborative editing](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual//configuration_files/collaborative_documents_configuration.html) functions
- Have decent [community](https://forum.owncloud.org/)
- written in [php](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual//installation/system_requirements.html)
- can create [share link](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual//configuration_files/file_sharing_configuration.html)
- can [connect to LDAP](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/admin_manual//configuration_user/user_auth_ldap.html)

Comment: A requirement was not written in PHP.

Comment: Requirement was changed after the answer. See the edit history. In the original it was "or php".